# How to obtain username from UserID in Telegram?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am using [Python-Telegram-Bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) API to create a bot. I get people's userID and username when they start the bot.
The userID doesn't change ever but the username can be changed by the user any time.
So I have usernames and UserIDs, and I receive another username - I wish to figure out whether that username is of someone already in the existing list or not.
Basically need to find out username from userID or if there's any other way I'm open to it.

Comment: Is telegram API (not  the bot API) an option?

Answer (score 6):

thats why you always process messages using the users' IDs

but to answer your question, you can either get the user's username directly using the `user` object, for example `update.message.from_user.username` or `update.effective_user.username`
or use `bot.getchat(chat_id)` to get an user object of a certain chat (which could be an user's private chat