# Can we get user name directly from user_id via telegram bot api?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-api

I want to get user names of my bot members and I have only there user_IDs.

I know how to get user_name if we work with channels or groups with `getChatMember` or other methods and need to pass `chat_id` as well as `user_id` and also if someone sends a message to bot than we can get `chat object` or `user boject` and can retrieve there `user_name`, `first_name` and other data.

But both senerios not works with bot when I want to get data only with user_names

Is there any API available for this situation. :{

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691233/how-to-obtain-username-from-userid-in-telegram) answer your question?

Comment: Short answer, YES but only if the user contacted your bot in the first place.

Comment: @Aven thanks for your quick reply, but your mentioned post is not compitable with my situation. I dont have user object now. but user_ids for which I want to grab user_name or first_name is contacted my bot first and I can send all of them message with requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?text=Hi&chat_id=<user_id>") but now when my bots getUpdates clear after some time how I can get again a user object

Comment: `getChatMember` works for channels and groups when I try `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getChatMember?chat_id=<channel_chat_id>&user_id=<user_id>` this will return a json object like `{"ok":true, "result":{"user":"id":000000000,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"FN","username":"username","language_code":"en"},"status":"creator","is_anonymous":false}}` but on try `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getChatMember?chat_id=<bot_chat_id>&user_id=<user_id>` I am getting user_not_found error but even Im a user of the bot `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: user not found"}`

Comment: do you have chat_id?

Comment: yes, I retrive my bots_chat_id using getMe method